# How could I get information consistently without attributeerror?

Tags: python, selenium

I used python to get listed companies description from website.

I intended that this code would get information consistently, but it just works only one time and occurs the attribute error.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wb = load_workbook("listedcorp.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

col_B = ws["B"]
# print(col_B)
# for cell in col_B:
#     print(cell.value)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# browser.maximize_window()

for cell in col_B:
    url = "https://finance.naver.com/item/main.nhn?code={}".format(cell.value)
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    ov = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"summary_info"}).get_text()
    print(str.strip(ov) + '\n\n')
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

and here is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVym3.jpg)

Please let me know what problem causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content needs a moment to be generated so you should wait until your elements presence is located before create your `BeautifulSoup` object from `driver.page_source`:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#summary_info')))
```

###### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

l = ['102280','002900']
url = 'https://finance.naver.com/item/main.naver?code='
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

for code in l:
    driver.get(url+code)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#summary_info')))
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    if soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"summary_info"}):
        ov = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"summary_info"}).get_text()
    else:
        ov = 'no text found'
    print(str.strip(ov) + '\n\n')
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your insight, this is helpful. thanks